# How to remove subset dictionaries from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, and some of them are subsets:

```
l = [
    {'zero': 'zero', 'one': 'example', 'two': 'second'}, 
    {'zero': 'zero', 'one': 'example', 'two': 'second', 'three': 'blabla'},
    {'zero': 'zero'},
    {'zero': 'non-zero', 'one': 'example'}, ...
]
```

And I want to create a new list of dictionaries that do not contain a subset of dictionaries.

```
res = [
    {'zero': 'zero', 'one': 'example', 'two': 'second', 'three': 'blabla'},
    {{'zero': 'non-zero', 'one': 'example'}, ...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This work around will create a new list that only contains dictionaries that are not subsets of any other dictionary in the list

```py
res = [
    d for d in l 
    if not any(set(d.items()).issubset(set(other.items()))
    for other in l if other != d)
    ]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[{'zero': 'zero', 'one': 'example', 'two': 'second', 'three': 'blabla'},
 {'zero': 'non-zero', 'one': 'example'}]
```